# Flipping CardView in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-listview, xamarin, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am trying to implement a CardView flip in a RecyclerView. I just cannot figure out a simple solution. I have a working CardView where i can display a list of card using the recycler view. The problem is, how to show the back of the card if user click the card. I want to use animation and change the front of the card to the back of the card. Can someone give a simple animation and example of the card layout.
My current example is pretty much copy of this [example](http://kvenkataprasad.blogspot.com/2015/01/recyclerview-example-with-on-click_8.html) where a new activity is being created. Where as i need the card to flip 180 degree and show the description. Is the a way to achieve it?

```
+------------------+ +------------------+
|+----------------+| |+----------------+|
||  front         || ||  back          ||
|+----------------+| |+----------------+|
|+----------------+| |+----------------+|
||  front         || ||  front         ||
|+----------------+| |+----------------+|
```

Comment: No one should do this for you. [Read this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question,but this answer may help someone in future.

You can make use of this library

> https://github.com/sachinvarma/EasyFlipView

Put this inside your gradle,

**compile 'com.github.sachinvarma:EasyFlipView:2.0.4'**

The xml will be like,

```
<com.wajahatkarim3.easyflipview.EasyFlipView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:flipOnTouch="true"
    app:flipEnabled="true"
    app:flipDuration="400"
    app:flipType="vertical" //horizontal or vertical
    >

    <!-- Back Layout Goes Here -->
    <include layout="@layout/flash_card_layout_back"/>

    <!-- Front Layout Goes Here -->
    <include layout="@layout/flash_card_layout_front"/>

</com.wajahatkarim3.easyflipview.EasyFlipView>
```

You can see a demo gif [here](https://github.com/sachinvarma/EasyFlipView/blob/master/Art/demo.gif).

Thanks to Wajahat karim.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html). It's a standard Android widget.